# probability of sorted array with duplicate numbers

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have a sequence of ***n*** numbers 
{a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,a<sub>3</sub>,...a<sub>n</sub>}
 where some of the numbers are **repeated**. What is the **probability** that the sequence is **sorted**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll assume that you intended to imply that all permutations of the $n$ numbers are equiprobable.

If number $x_j$ is present $n_j$ times, with $1\le j\le k$ and $\sum_jn_j=n$, there are

$$
\binom n{n_1,\ldots,n_k}=\frac{n!}{\prod_jn_j!}
$$

distinguishable arrangements. They are equiprobable and exactly one of them is ordered, so the probability for this to happen is

$$
\frac{\prod_jn_j!}{n!}\;.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Usually, if the numbers were not repeated the probability would be 1/n! where n! is the number of possible sorted combination while just one is the correct one. As the number can be repeated, the number of each repeated numbers (for example {2,2,...,2}) can be between 1 to n and the number of different repeated numbers  can be between 2 and n/2  (for example {1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4, ... ,n/2,n/2}). So the probability will be {C(n, 1) + C(n, 2) + ... + C(n, n)} / n!.{C(n/2, 2) + C(n/2, 3) + C(n/2, n/2)}

Comment: what do you mean by c(1,2) or c(1,n)?

Comment: I edited the formula to the correct one. C is the combination: [=>the link for the formula](http://www.mathwords.com/c/combination_formula.htm)