# Expected number of permutations required to sort a list of numbers

Tags: probability, expectation, sorting

Given a list of N numbers if we are performing random permutations each time and checking whether the list is sorted, what will be the expected number of permutations required to sort that list?

Comment: Have you tried applying the definition of the expectation? If you are familiar with geometric series, that really is all you have to do to get an answer.

Comment: Are the numbers distinct?

Comment: @NP-hard No there can be numbers repeating

Comment: Could you please let us know the source of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it happens, [probability of sorted array with duplicate numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843047) was asked just a few hours ago. If number $x_j$ is present $n_j$ times, with $1\le j\le k$ and $\sum_jn_j=n$, the probability for a uniformly randomly chosen permutation to order the list is

$$
\frac{\prod_jn_j!}{n!}\;,
$$

so the expected number of permutations required is

$$
\frac{n!}{\prod_jn_j!}=\binom n{n_1,\ldots,n_k}\;,
$$

the number of distinguishable arrangements of the numbers.